# Riemann Integration

Tags: real-analysis

Let:
$f : [0, \infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ 
and
$g : [0, \infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ 
be two continuous functions such that for all x we have
$\mid f(x)\mid \space \le \space g(x)$
.  Moreover, assume that there is a number M such that for all b > 0

$$\int_0^{b} g(x) dx \le M$$

(a) Define the sequence b<sub>n</sub> :=  $\int_0^n g(x)\space dx$. Explain why the sequence must converge.

(b) Explain why the sequence ${b_n}$   must be a Cauchy Sequence

(c) Define the sequence a<sub>n</sub> := $\int_0^n f(x)\space dx$.  Prove that the sequence ${a_n}$ must converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: a) Show that $b_n$ is bounded and monotonically increasing. b) Every convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ is Cauchy. c) Show that $a_n$ must be Cauchy (knowing that $b_n$ is Cauchy should help).

Comment: But suppose we have that g(x) = sin(x) and f(x) = -sin(x).  It appears that this particular assignment agrees with the initial conditions.  Yet b<sub>n</sub> does not converge, since the values of this sequence oscillate at values between 0 and 2 for any n $\ge$ M, where M denotes some real number.

Comment: for these function the inequality $|f(x)|\le g(x)$ does not hold.

Comment: Thankyou for your responses!